# Docker-compose up working but docker run not work

Tags: .net, mongodb, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

When i try to run "docker-compose up". It is working. But when i try to run "docker run denexbackend_denex-service". I am getting mongo connection timeout error.

*[Denex.Backend](https://github.com/mwlt68/Denex.BackEnd) is open source project.*

**appsettings.json**

```
  "MongoDbSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://mongodb-service:27017",
    "Database": "DenexDB"
  },
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  denex-service:
    container_name: denex
    image: mevlutgur/denex.backend:latest
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3003:80
  mongodb-service:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    volumes:
      - denex-data:/data/db
volumes:
  denex-data:
```

**docker-compose.yml**  (After trying some solutions)

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongodb-service:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    volumes:
      - denex-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - samplenetwork
  denex-service:
    container_name: denex-backend
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3003:80
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-service
    networks:
      - samplenetwork
volumes:
  denex-data:

networks:
  samplenetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-jammy AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY src/WebApi/Denex.WebApi/Denex.WebApi.csproj ./src/WebApi/Denex.WebApi/
COPY src/Core/Denex.Domain/Denex.Domain.csproj ./src/Core/Denex.Domain/
COPY src/Core/Denex.Application/Denex.Application.csproj ./src/Core/Denex.Application/
COPY src/Infrastructure/Denex.Persistance/Denex.Persistance.csproj ./src/Infrastructure/Denex.Persistance/
COPY tests/WebApi.UnitTest/WebApi.UnitTest.csproj ./tests/WebApi.UnitTest/

RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY src/WebApi/Denex.WebApi/. ./src/WebApi/Denex.WebApi/
COPY src/Core/Denex.Domain/. ./src/Core/Denex.Domain/
COPY src/Core/Denex.Application/. ./src/Core/Denex.Application/
COPY src/Infrastructure/Denex.Persistance/. ./src/Infrastructure/Denex.Persistance/
COPY tests/WebApi.UnitTest/. ./tests/WebApi.UnitTest/

WORKDIR /app/src/WebApi/Denex.WebApi
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

WORKDIR /app/tests/WebApi.UnitTest
RUN dotnet test --verbosity quiet

# build runtime image

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-jammy AS runtime
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/src/WebApi/Denex.WebApi/out ./
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Denex.WebApi.dll"]
```

**Error message**

```
Unhandled exception. System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongodb-service:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongodb-service:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, ValueStopwatch stopwatch)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress, AddressFamily family)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.ResolveEndPoints(EndPoint initial)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2022-11-13T19:16:54.6844686Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2022-11-13T19:16:54.6844692Z" }] }.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterServerSelection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupported(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl.ListCollectionNames(ListCollectionNamesOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Denex.Persistance.Extensions.MongoImportExtension.AddMongoImport(IConfiguration configuration) in /app/src/Infrastructure/Denex.Persistance/Extensions/MongoImportExtension.cs:line 19
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /app/src/WebApi/Denex.WebApi/Program.cs:line 24
```

Comment: The mongdb container started successfully?

Comment: when i try "docker compose up". But "docker run" did not start. @Turing85

Comment: When i run "docker-compose up" it create an image. And i try to run that image. @Turing85

Comment: Ah. Yeah. this is expected. The compose file starts the mongodb. This is obviously not started if we only start the `denex-service`. Thus, the connection fails.

Comment: The creation of an image in this case is only a side-effect of `docker compose up`. The backend cannot function without a mongodb as it seems. If you want to start everything separately, start a mongdb container first and rewrite the configuration so that `denex-service` connects to that mongodb-instance. But to be honest: just using the `docker-compose.yml` is simpler and more convenient.

Comment: In fact i want to do below steps.
"docker-compose build" > "docker-compose push" > "docker pull x" > "docker run x" give same db error. @Turing85

Comment: Again: you need a mongodb.The mongodb must be reachable under the name `mongodb-service` and the run on port`27017` (or there is a way to reconfigure the database connection through environment variables - I am no expert in .net).

Comment: Or alternatively: on the receiving end, provide a `docker-compose` identical to the one you used to push, but instead of building the image for the `denex-service`, pull it from the repository it was pushed to.

Answer (score 1):

Docker compose is kind of an abstraction layer on top of docker containers.

So with compose you have services denex-service and mongodb-service, they are treated as hostnames/dns names so in denex-service appsettings.json you can reference it with the service name mongodb-service. Each service is running 1 container by default but compose services can be scaled with the --scale flag on `docker compose up ... --scale denex-service=5` so denex-service would be served 5 containers, of course the app must support to be scaled up.

Also compose projects run in their own docker network by default, created on compose up and removed with compose down, but since you explictly set `samplenetwork` you compose project will run in this network. If you do `docker network ls` after compose up you will see `samplenetwork`

To run your stuff with bare containers with docker you need to first start the mongo-service container, give the name of it mongo-service (--name flag) so the .NET appsettings.json doesn't need to be modified. After the container named mongo-service is up and running you can start the .NET app.

Optionally you can create a separate network for these containers and run them with it (--network flag) instead of the default bridge network, but first you need to create the network.

`docker network create samplebarenetwork`

All in all, docker compose is much more convenient to use than "bare" containers but it is good to know or even mandatory to understand how containers work. Buckle up, because the next stop is kubernetes ;)

BTW! you should use the Compose V2 that is a subcommand of docker (without dash between docker and compose): `docker compose` instead of the old compose cli `docker-compose`: https://www.docker.com/blog/announcing-compose-v2-general-availability/

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating a network when running your non-compose docker commands ?

You could do :

```
docker network create \
  --driver bridge \
  --subnet 182.18.0.1/24 \
  --gateway 182.18.0.1 \
  samplenetwork
```

followed by

```
docker run \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker \
  --name mongodb-service \
  -p 27018:27017 \
  -v 'denex-data:/data/db' \
  --network samplenetwork \
  -d mongo
```

and then after that you make sure you've built a version of your container from your Dockerfile

```
docker build -t denex-service -f Dockerfile .
```

And lastly, you run the version of the container you've just built locally :

```
docker run \
  --name denex-backend \
  -p 3003:80 \
  --network samplenetwork \
  -d denex-service
```

Good luck, and make sure you double-check my container names and stuff, I could have a typo somewhere but this should work for you.